# .trim() and regular expressions producing unexpected results

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I wrote a fairly simple regular expression to detect when a string looks like it could be an email:

```
var looksLikeEmail = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/gi;
```

I'm using Knockout and the string being tested is the value of a textarea.

Essentially, say we have the value of the textarea in a variable `text`. This value was, for example, the typed in value `abc@example.com`.

What's odd, is it seems like, even though `text === text.trim()`, `looksLikeEmail.test(text)` returns true, but `looksLikeEmail.test(text.trim())` returns false.

On the other hand, if I manually create the string `var test2 = 'abc@example.com'`, it does not have this issue.

This seems to indicate to me that the textarea is inserting some odd characters or something... that .trim() is doing something weird with.  But `test.length === test2.length` and `test.length === test.trim().length`

Does anyone know how to make this behave correctly?

I've written up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLJdd/) to quickly demonstrate the behavior...

If you go to the fiddle and try typing in an email... you will see the problem. another weird behavior: add a space after the email, then remove it. /confused

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have to say this behavior does look weird. Initially, abc@example.com says true/false/true. When I add a space at the end, it becomes false/true/false. However, when I remove the space at the end again, it becomes false/true/true even though it's the same input as I had at the start.

Comment: exactly. I am trying to find some explanation for this but there is nothing that comes to mind. I'm almost ready to conclude that this is a bug with the regex implementation in javascript (i wonder if it is browser specific, actually).

Comment: Note: just tried in IE and the behavior seems identical to Chrome.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using /g? By removing that I got it to work a bit more reliably, but if there's a reason you're using global matching we'll have to look for another solution.

Comment: @OlafKeijsers you're right. That was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.test()`, just like `.exec()` will remember the last index of a match when using a global regex, and try to match from it onward, failing on the second call. Just remove the `/g` option from your regex - it doesn't make sense to have `/g` in a non-multiline regex which matches beginning and end.

Comment: crap. I was rewriting this regex from another one and I didn't think about the implications of the /g flag. thanks for the help!